# Background Image in my game is covering my drawings Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am doing a small mini-game with some shapes.

```
        Main jframe = new Main("Main");

        JLabel backpic1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("D:/User/Desktop/Other/Cloud.jpg") );
        jframe.add(backpic1);//background

        jframe.setSize(600,600);//setting the size
        jframe.setVisible(true);
```

So after I add a background, the background covers everything

```
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g1 = (Graphics2D) g;
        shape-1.paint(g);
        shape-2.paint(g);
        shape-3.paint(g);
        shape-4.paint(g);
        user.paint(g);
    }
```

The game is still functioning behind the background, I have tried couple of things to fix it, but they don't seem to work:(

Comment: Why is the background a JLabel? Maybe it should be the same type as the other shapes you're drawing?

Comment: Don't override paint (especially of frames), strangely enough, when children are painted, the parent may no be painted. Create a custom component (extending from JPanel), use its paintComponent to paint the background image. Extend this class again, overriding its paintComponent and draw your other graphics, making sure to call super.paintComponent in both cases

Answer (score -1):

What exactly you want to do with the repaint method?

The way you add the background..

If you just add a JLabel over the other it's wrong..

1. *One way is to replace the image of the JLabel you already use as     background.*

   ```
   backpic1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("the other background Image"));
   ```

It is logical the background to be covered  cause you use paint method wich covers the content panel of the window.

2. If you want to use the paint method **don't add The JLabel** just **use JPanel**
   or the panel the frame containing by default.

Let me know if that works for you...

Comment: Nope, that did not work, or I might be doing something wrong.